# Perform 'select * from (select * from ...)' query in ef core 2.2

Tags: c#, postgresql, subquery, postgis, ef-core-2.2

I am trying to perform a similar query with a subquery to this (SQL) in c# using entity framework core 2.2

```
select ST_LengthSpheroid(ST_MakeLine(a."Location"),'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]') AS Length
from (select * from "Logs" where "CarId" = 191
      order by "Id") as a;
```

in entity framework > 2.0, I've tried to perform left joins, but with custom functions, I run into ef core warnings or errors. Are there any proper ways to implement that query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, maybe anyone knows a better solution, but after some researches I couldn't achieve that with *pure* ef core, so I have used `FromSql`

```
var queryable = qLogs.FromSql("select * from \"" + tableName + "\" order by \"" + orderField + "\"");

var result = qCars.Select(x => new RouteModel
{
   Mileage = Math.Round(
       queryable
           .Where(y => y.CarId == x.Id)
           .Select(y => PostgisExtensions.ST_LengthSpheroid(
                    PostgisExtensions.ST_MakeLine(
                        PostgisExtensions.ST_GeomFromText(y.Location.AsText(),          PostgisConstants.MetricSrid)
                    ),
                   PostgisConstants.SpheroidWgs84)
           )
           .FirstOrDefault() / 1000),
 .....
```

So now I can `orderby` using subselect without `groupby` or `distinct on`.
Works perfectly without any ef core warnings and generates expected query:

```
  SELECT ROUND(COALESCE((
      SELECT ST_LengthSpheroid(ST_MakeLine(ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(x0."Location"), 4326)), 'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]')
      FROM (
          select * from "Logs" order by "FixedAt"
      ) AS x0
      WHERE (x0."CarId" = x."Id")
      LIMIT 1
  ), 0.0) / 1000.0) AS "Mileage", 
  .....
```

Comment: But hey, it does not use AsEnumerable() just like every SO answer out here

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
select ST_LengthSpheroid(ST_MakeLine(TrackerLogs.Location),'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]') AS Length
from TrackerLogs
where CarId = 191
order by Id
```